# project with many typescript files fails with "could not find file XXXX" error

Tags: typescript

yesterday all of a sudden i started getting typescript compile errors... the error was along the lines of:

could not find file "XXXXXXX"...

the strange thing is that the file being referred to ("XXXXXXX") in the message has an invalid path due to a charecter being cut off... so for example the correct actual file is "c:\project\app.ts" but the error message makes reference to "c:\projec\app.ts"... notice the "t" is missing from "project"...

anyway, it turns out that my problem is already documented here: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/597

this link is somewhat dated... so my question however is whether or not this is still the valid workaround???? i am using the latest version 0.9.1... this seems like a serious issue that would affect many users with large projects with many TS files... so i suspect by now that this issue has perhaps been fixed and perhaps i am doing something wrong... thank you

Answer (score 2):

The workaround at that link is still correct. The issue with long/non-ASCII build paths has not been fixed yet; I would anticipate it will not be resolved until version 1.0.